# No XsltListViewWebPart was found on this page

Tags: content-type

I've installed stand-alone SP2010 on Windows Server 2008 R2 - no problems during installation.

I set up a content type that inherits the 'Page' type and added some new content type fields.

I then added a new default layout page for the content type.  I used Designer to add a couple of the new content type fields to the page, checked it in and approved it.

I set up a document library and specify the new content type for it.

I try to add. The initial form appears to accept the title, description and URL, and allows me to select my new page layout.

I then click 'Create' and it crashes. The message in the log is:

> No XsltListViewWebPart was found on this page[/_layouts/CreatePage.aspx?

Answer (score 1):

Your custom content type can be used only in a *Pages* library (not a regular document library).

[Error when creating new Article Page in a document library on SharePoint 2010](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010setup/thread/41594f9b-ac66-4ce6-91b7-2745f250e757)

> The Article Page content type is
>   specifically designed for publishing
>   and won't work in a regular document
>   library.  It can only be used in a
>   Pages document library that is created
>   when you turn on Publishing.  The
>   pages document library has specific
>   extensions for page layout content
>   types.  Although it may have worked in
>   SharePoint 2007 it shouldn't have and
>   evidently the feature set in 2010 now
>   makes it impossible.